# @SerializedName("home") is it invalid annotation in order to implement parcelable

Tags: android, serialization, retrofit, parcelable, pojo

I am using **Retrofit** and have many pojo class according to json. Since I am Using **Gson** parsing I need to use:

```
@SerializedName("home")
private List<Home> home = new ArrayList<>();

@SerializedName("away")
private List<Away> Away= new ArrayList<>();

public List<Home> getHome() {
  return home;
}
```

Now I want to implement **Parcelable** in all pojo class.

I am not very sure will `@serialized` name annotation use java serialization or just a name check annotation?

Will it add any runtime exceptions while unmarshalling in parcel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with `SerializedName` and `Parcelable`.

[`SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) is a GSON annotation for specifying JSON property names and has really nothing to do with Java serialization.

When you implement `Parcelable`, you write the marshal/unmarshal code yourself (or generate it yourself) and no reflection or annotation lookup needs to happen at runtime.

Comment: Okay.Thanks man for such  for your quick response. One more input i would need.. when accessing these variable what is preferred way .. to use getter setters of this class or accessing from write to parcel method